# How to design a poster with so much written content in it?

Tags: print-design, posters

Consider there is a website full of text, and someone asks you to design a poster from it. Which methods do you suggest for designing this poster?

---

***Update:*** the website is *"Semantic Version Specification"* (semver.org) . i should design a poster from it.

Comment: It *highly* depends on the structure of the website so I guess there can be no general advice except “simplify as much as you can”

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. I think there's potential for a good question here, but most will find it too vague to answer well. If you could give us an example that would help a lot! It would also be helpful to know the purpose of the poster.

Comment: i update the question @Brendan

Comment: Then that's likely not a poster.

Comment: It also depends on the purpose. If it's to **promote the website** as the final source of info, you want something simple, clear and eye-catching that gives the gist then a short-form web address (plus maybe a QR code). If it's to **be the source of info** itself, as an info poster people will take time to read, you need to do the above, and also, design a hierarchy and structure for the text that helps people skim to the bit that is relevant to them and guides them through the content. See also [Examples of good academic poster design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9452/)

Comment: Oh, and think [hierarchy hierarchy hierarchy](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=l0QPECGQySYC&pg=PA122).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is: visualize as much as possible. Posters live from being easy to digest. If people see clutters of headings, paragraphs and some images randomly thrown in they usually get lost and bored. I once was told that a person in a crowd is not willing to spend more than five minutes looking at the poster, the very first seconds decide if a closer looks is worthwhile (pay attention to large objects and the title).

Help people by navigating them through a poster (arrows, clear spacings, headings with numbers, ...). It seems trivial but most people are used to read from top left to bottom right, so don't interfere with that.

Don't forget about choosing an appealing colour theme (if desired) and assigning colours to messages and objects (e.g. all subheadings have same colours). Think carefully about background pictures as they may distract.

On your website you have a lot of text; get rid of all information that don't contribute to your main message. Focus on this very message. You don't have much space to waste. In case you are presenting the poster have some handouts ready (preferably repeating the theme and layout of your poster) that contain the website address - most people will not write it down or remember for themselves. Also put it on your poster.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you must to determine important information and trash. Reread many times and cutout little mess every time. Take the gist. After that you can play with small chunk of main information.

If you have data - try to vizualizate it.